# Tag rename request [constructorhd] -> [constructor-hd]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-rename-request

I noticed [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/313081/162442) about Constructor HD get edited to have the (new) [constructorhd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructorhd) tag, which I believe was a typo.

The game is called Constructor HD, so the tag should be [constructor-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructor-hd), however, since the former tag exists, I cannot edit the correct one in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just noticed this myself. Done.

Comment: That was quick.

Comment: @Vemonus - I finished the edit, then got the notification of a new meta question. :-)